# How do you convert a B-Tree to a B* tree? / Minimum Fill Logic

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

I read that the only difference between a B Tree and a B* Tree is the fill factor. The minimum fill factor of a B-Tree is 1/2, and the minimum fill factor for a B* tree is 2/3.

So, for a B-Tree, the max number of keys and children you have is 2*degree (minimum number of elements in a node). If I have a minimum fill factor of 3, the most keys a node can have is 6. That logic gives me this:

```
keyHolder = new int[2 * degree - 1];
children = new BTreeNode[2 * degree];
```

That worked just fine and my B-Tree worked as expected. So, when I went to modify my B-Tree into a B* tree, I thought that the max number of children and keys must be (3 * degree)/2. That gave me this:

```
keyHolder = new int[((3 * degree)/2) - 1];
children = new BStarTreeNode[(3 * degree)/2];
```

**Problem:**
However, now the split child method throws an array out of bounds exception when I try to copy keys from temp here:

```
temp.keyHolder[j] = node.keyHolder[j + degree];
```

**Question:**
I'm not really asking why the code doesn't work, but rather, what's wrong with my logic. If the only difference between the two trees is just the fill factor, shouldn't the only thing you need to do to convert one to another is change the max number of keys and children for a given node? Everything else, including how you split the nodes up once the root is full should stay the same. You just need to change the max limit at which the split takes place right?

Thanks for any help in advance.

**Relevant Code:**
I placed the splitChild method below in case it helps:

```
public void splitChild(int i, BStarTreeNode node) {
    BStarTreeNode temp = new BStarTreeNode(node.degree - 1, node.leaf);
    temp.numKeys = degree - 1;

    // Copy the degree-1 keys into temo from node
    for (int j = 0; j < degree - 1; j++) {
        temp.keyHolder[j] = node.keyHolder[j + degree];

    }

    // If this node is not a leaf, copy the degree children
    if (node.leaf == false) {
        for (int j = 0; j < degree; j++) {
            temp.children[j] = node.children[j + degree];
        }
    }

    // Reduce the number of keys in node
    node.numKeys = degree - 1;

// Since this node is going to have a new child,
    // create space of new child
    for (int j = numKeys; j >= i + 1; j--) {
        children[j + 1] = children[j];
    }
    // Link the new child to this node
    children[i + 1] = temp;

      //Find location of
    // new key and move all greater keys one space ahead
    for (int j = numKeys - 1; j >= i; j--) {
        keyHolder[j + 1] = keyHolder[j];
    }

    // Copy the middle key of node 
    keyHolder[i] = node.keyHolder[degree - 1];


// Increment count of keys in this node
    numKeys = numKeys + 1;
}
```

The code I wrote is from [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/b-tree-set-1-insert-2/). I just rewrote it in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum number of keys per node doesn't change. It is still *2N*. What changes is the conditions where you must split and join.

When you split a full node you must acquire keys from the previous and successor nodes, so that the two new nodes satisfy `n >= 2*N/3`, and conversely when joining you must distribute keys back into the prior and successor nodes, as you will have too many keys for just one node.

Comment: Thanks! That made a lot of sense. So, do we pick 2N for the keys per node size just to make sure we have enough space in the array? I thought that number was tied to the fill size...but since its not, im guessing it can be anything like 3N or 4N.

Comment: Actually I would just call it *N*, the maximum number of keys = the order of the tree, and simplify the maths. You pick it based on the desired block size divided by the key size, or rather key+pointer size.

Comment: Great. That makes sense. I definitely like the idea of simplifying the math. Thanks!